# Wisdom of the Ancients

Tags: steganography, poetry

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

In the future, an ancient book of old proverbs in the form of haikus has been found, here's the transcription of the first page:

> Flies haphazardly
>   so small but very scary
>   we flee from the bee
>
> Have too many clothes
>   running late and nothing fits
>   tell me what to wear
>
> Baby keeps screaming
>   now she’s falling asleep
>   please don’t make her yell
>
> Client: I can’t login
>   Help: Is your caps lock on?
>   Patience: All time low
>
> Blizzard in winter
>   Jump off roof into pile — ow!
>   Boulder under snow

After further examination it seems that another portion of wisdom has been hidden within. What does it say?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The last word of each haiku is "**bee wear yell low snow**," which gives the ancient wisdom "**beware yellow snow**."

Comment: Correct! I know it was going to be super easy, I just thought it would be fun :)